# Having trouble with including dataTables.css in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-5

Cannot get the ascending and descending order markings on the table and in the Network console I see the following errors:

```
sort_asc.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
sort_both.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
```

I could not figure as of where to include the images and how to include them in the `dataTables.css`. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your include code

Comment: I'm sorry ..what does it mean??